# bug when try to send file in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, file-transfer, nettcpbinding

when I tried to send file using WCF service I get this exception

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   Error in deserializing body of request
>   message for operation 'Send_File'. The
>   maximum array length quota (16384) has
>   been exceeded while reading XML data.
>   This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxArrayLength property
>   on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML
>   reader.

I converted the file at first to array of Bytes before I sent it 
this is client configuration who sent the file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpBinding" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00"
        receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" transactionFlow="false"
        transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
        maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxConnections="30"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="100000000"
          maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="10:00:00"
          enabled="false" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpBinding" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00"
        receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000"
          maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="10:00:00" />
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="filebehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2000000000"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/ChatRoom/service" behaviorConfiguration="filebehavior"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding"
      contract="ChatRoom" name="TcpBinding">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="my_machine\ASPNET" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/ChatRoom/service" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" contract="ChatRoom" name="HttpBinding">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="my_machine\ASPNET" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

server configration

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="securingWSHttpBinding">
        </binding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_ChatRoomServices" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="10:00:00"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
        <services>
      <service name="ChatRoomService.ChatRoom"
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ChatRoomService.IChatRoom" name="TcpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="service" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ChatRoomService.IChatRoom" name="HttpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="MexBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/ChatRoom/"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/ChatRoom/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

how I can solve this exception ?

Comment: Are you setting the endpoint in your client and/or service to use the above binding with the bindingConifguration attribute in the endpoint element?  If you're not, WCF will use the default values for the binding.

Comment: I added the endpoint <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/ChatRoom/service"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding"
          contract="ChatRoom" name="TcpBinding">
        <identity>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your bindings don't even match between the client and the server :)

Your client has a NetTcpBinding and a DualWsHttpBinding, and your server has a wsHttpBinding. i'm surprised they can even communicate to each other, to be honest.  (Unless you're using WCF 4.0, in which case you will have default bindings and endpoints).

Secondly, your service config file isn't referencing the delared binding - there is no bindingConfiguration attribute on the endpoints, so if communication is established the channel will use the default values for the specified binding protocol.

The client configuration looks ok, try this for the server (I'm only including the NetTcpBinding protocol, and adding the behaviorName and bindingConfiguration attributes to the endpoint - the other bindings would be similar):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="TcpBinding" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxConnections="30" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />       
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="10:00:00" enabled="false" />     
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings> 
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="filebehavior">       
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2000000000"/>     
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors> 
  </behaviors> 
  <service>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/ChatRoom/service" behaviorConfiguration="filebehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBinding" contract="ChatRoom" name="TcpBinding">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="my_machine\ASPNET" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>    
  </service>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this when specifying the service behavior, and endpoint behavior

on the client side, when you specify the endpoint, set the behavior name:

```
<endpoint behaviorConfiguration = "myBehavior"/>
```

and then specify this behavior:

```
<behaviours>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="a number that is big enough"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

on the server:

when you specify the 'service' and the 'endpoint', attach a serviceBehavior and endpointBehavior respectively, as for the client.

Comment: You'll probably want to modify the service's config file, not the client's - at least, I've run into maxStringContentLength issues before where it mattered which config I adjusted.  Also, just to prevent any confusion, the value for maxItemsInObjectGraph needs to be a number that is big enough for what you are sending - don't use the literal string "a number that is big enough" as the value.

Comment: @lockstock where should I add this in client?or server ?

Comment: @Tim I didn't understand this part You'll probably want to modify the service's config file, not the client's where can i find service's config file ?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I was assuming salamonti would work that out. Its good to specify a value that is only as big as you need, to avoid potential security issues such as denial of service attacks.

Comment: @salamonti - the service's config file should be with the service's host (in IIS, it will be the web.config, for a windows service or self-hosted service it will be the app.config).

Comment: @Salamonti, well when I last had this issue, I had to modify both client and server config to resolve it.

Comment: @lockstock - No problem.  I only added the clarification because the other day I saw a poster do just that - put a literal string value in the attribute for their config file. :)

Comment: @lockstock where should I add this behavior part in config file in binding or where ?

Comment: @salamonti - can you edit your question and post the <system.serviceModel> section of both the client and service's config files?  Chances are something's not matching up.

Comment: @salamonti - thanks.  I've added an answer that should help, I hope.

Comment: @lockstock thanks so much for answering if I can make 2 right answered i did

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try Streamed transfer mode in your case.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx